# Create MobileServiceClient object without Application Key

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I need to create a MobileServiceClient object without Application Key.. How can I do it?

Comment: what language are you using?  You can typically pass null, nil, etc in for the key to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your response ..I am using java.. But if I pass null for Application Key, I am getting Exception..

Answer (score 2):

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("http://localhost:46742");
```

There is an overload of the constructor with only the URL as parameter.

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But I am using java language..how can i achieve it in java ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it was fixed in the github [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/commit/ae76ceed96e783f49fdbe05fdd14d74312ac7142) last spring (it is/was a known issue that the constructor forced the use of an application key)

That said, looking at the source for the Android SDK 1.1.5 this fix isn't included. I'll ask around about a newer version of the Android SDK to see if there are plans to release it anytime soon.